# Make a programable call with generated TwiML file in runtime

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-twiml

I use Twilio in order to make a programable call. As you can know Twilio uses TwiML files for a call configurations. I would like to build the TwiML file in runtime.

I use Twilio dependency to work with API, so call looks like:

```
Call.creator(new PhoneNumber("to"), new PhoneNumber("from"), new URI("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml")).create();
```

I've found that I can build my own TwiML using the implementation of `TwiML` class from the dependency.

```
new Say.Builder("Hello!")
            .language(Say.Language.EN_AU)
            .voice(Say.Voice.MAN)
            .build()
            .toXml();
```

How can I pass a created TwiML to make a call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can for example pass your endpoint to `Call` configuration instead of file - `http://your/server/url/calls` and resnpond with generated TwiML from there.